# Iterating list from Angular controller setting scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am making a call to my backend, which returns a list of objects as JSON. Now, I want to iterate these in the frontend in my Angular app.

However, when the HTML i wrote below is rendered, nothing is shown. I have no idea why, as I was sure this was the syntax.

There are no JavaScript errors in the console. Also, I was unsure if it was the `$scope` inside an async call that caused my problem, but it seems that if I copy the response from the API out and puts it as a string (therefore sync and not async), nothing is shown still.

Any idea where my bug is? (*Disclaimer: as I am new to Angular, I might have made a newbie mistake!*)

**My angular app:**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute'])

app.config(function($routeProvider) {   
    $routeProvider.when('/front', { 
        templateUrl: '/templates/front.html',
        controller: 'FrontController'
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/front'})

});

app.controller('FrontController',['$scope',function($scope) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/api/serials',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $scope.serials = data;
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert('fejl');
        }
    });

    $scope.datatitle = 'hheeh';
}]);
```

**The AJAX call:**

In my network category, I can see the following are returned from the API:

```
[{"_id":"53cf8b80a20055c6eebf80b1","serial":"1231323123","game":"World of Warcraft","date":"2013-12-31T23:00:00.000Z"}]
```

**My HTML:**

The HTML rendered in the frontend is: `"Angular works: 8"`

My code is:

```
Angular works: {{ 4+4 }}

{{serial.length}}
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="serial in serials">{{serial}}</li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**:

Console log of data:

[image]

Comment: are you getting desired data in  $scope.serials?

Comment: if i say console.log(data), I get the correct data yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a factory and inject that in the controller. Here is how you can create a factory and use it in your case:

```
app.factory('SerialService', function($http) {
    return {
        getSerials: function(callback) {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: "/api/serials"
            }).
            success(function(data) {
                callback(data);
            });
    };

});
```

and in your controller:

```
app.controller('FrontController',['$scope','SerialService',function($scope,SerialService) {

    SerialService.getSerials(function(data){
       $scope.serials = data;
    });

    $scope.datatitle = 'hheeh';
}]);
```

More on [Angular Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using jQuery's $.ajax and Angular is not notified.  You could use $scope.$apply() but that would be hackish.  Instead inject the $http service.  It will make you life easier.

Better yet move all that logic to a factory or a service.  It will help you be more DRY.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are getting appropriate json object (as shown) in $scope.serials... you should write as below.

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="serial in serials">{{serial.serial}}{{serial.game}}{{serial.date}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I just modified my HTML to yours, and I made a console.log on the data which gives a correct object. Still, it shows nothing.. Hmm :)

Comment: just updated post with a pic :-) thanks for helping!

Comment: tell me is there anything in console.log($scope.serials)??? If yes tell me/show me how it comes. if not, use $scope.$apply() in below line.

Comment: Ah, sorry, misunderstood. If I say console.log($scope.serials), after I set it - it has the exact same value as shown in the picture.

Comment: If I say $scope.$apply(); below my line, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here.

The below HTML will print out the JSON representation of the full string.  To get an actual property value you have to do serial.xxxx.

```
<li data-ng-repeat="serial in serials">{{serial}}</li>
```

The second issue is that you are using $.ajax, which is a jQuery function and anything in the scope of that function will not automatically update the $scope in your controller.  You need to use the $http service:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Make sure to properly include the service.  If you use the $http service you will not have to manually do the $scope.$apply() and you will remove another jQuery dependency.